# incorrect php code output with embedded html

Tags: php, html, apache

I am trying to implement html code in my php code. I use

```
<?php
echo <<< _END
//HTML HERE
_END;
?>
```

The problem is that `_END;?>` shows on the page as well.

I edited directives for my websites folder in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mywebsite.conf` with this code and I access the php file with mydomain.com/test . No .php extension added. If I access mydomain.com/test.php than there is no _END;?> in my html output, which is correct.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.html [NC]

</IfModule>
```

Any idea why am I seeing `_END;?>` in my website?

It seems that hiding .html works as it should, but .php gets incorrectly interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra white space before or after the  `_END`. Here is a link that will explain it in more detail. [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)